# What was the PyQGIS class QgsCompostition changed to?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I am wondering what the old classes [`QgsComposition`](https://api.qgis.org/api/2.0/classQgsComposition.html) and `QgsComposerItem` where changed to in the current release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [Alessandro Pasotti's](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2018-March/052612.html) and [Nyall Dawson's](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2018-March/052620.html) QGIS Developer List responses:

> QgsComposition is gone in favor of the new layout classes: see
> https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayout.html
>
> Have a look to the tests for some usage examples:
> https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgslayout.py

> For reference, this is listed in API breaks:
> https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_Composer